# JSX element type 'HeaderPublic' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am using `nx workspace` for build the react ts app.

here is the lib component:

```
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
import styles from './header-public.module.scss';

export function HeaderPublic(): ReactElement {
  return (
    <div className={styles['container']}>
      <h1>Welcome to HeaderPublic!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeaderPublic;
```

here is the layout component:

```
import * as HeaderPublic from '@stonehenge/header-public';
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
import layoutStyle from './layout-public.module.scss';

export function LayoutPublic({ children }: { children: ReactElement }) {
  return (
    <section className={layoutStyle['app-wrapper']}>
      <header className="app-header">
        <HeaderPublic></HeaderPublic>//error
      </header>
      <main className="app-main">{children}</main>
      <footer className="app-footer"></footer>
    </section>
  );
}

export default LayoutPublic;
```

getting error at header component as:

`JSX element type 'HeaderPublic' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)`

`<main className="app-main">{children}</main>` works. but header throw error. any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

I imported the component like this:

`import { HeaderPublic } from '@stonehenge/header-public';` instead of

`import * as HeaderPublic from '@stonehenge/header-public';` now works fine.